# How to copy java package with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I am working with Gradle and I am trying to update/copy resources from one project to another. If I try

```
[...]
  //copies resource bundles from root project
  from ("cfg/resources") {
    into "cfg/resources"
  }
[...]
```

My package got copied to the cfg folder as expected like:

[image]

What I actually want to achieve is to keep my project structure like:

[image]

Any hint?

Comment: For me, the expected and what you want, look the same. Please add more details.

Comment: You are right. Once I created a Source Folder in my project with the given path cfg/resources and it looked as I wanted.

Comment: I am using Eclipse by the way, not sure if this is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I created a Source Folder in my project with the given path cfg/resources, it looked as I wanted. Even after deleting everything and copying again. I am using Eclipse by the way...